# For how long will we store your data?. Is this a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence

I have these two sentences in the legal text of my website. Then the context is a "legal context" and the sentences is about the data the visitors of my web send me.

Sentence 1: **For how long will we store your data?**

Sentence 2: **Who will your data be disclosed to?**

Is there a better way to write them?

Comment: (Your question may be flagged as off-topic but ...) They are both fine. Although I might write the first one as **How long will we store your data for?** (it is more natural sounding and parallels the structure of the other one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1 looks good. Perfect sentence structure sometimes does not work, so I'd use the same.

For second one, maybe you could say "Whom your data will be disclosed to?" I think it is whom because the one you ask is not the subject (doer). I think that'd be more formal but nowadays, even the natives are leaving using "whom" so it is your call.

Comment: If you are going to use 'whom', which is actually disappearing from colloquial speech, the more consistent sentence form would be "To whom will we disclose your data?" However to be pedantic on this topic is like saying "Up with which we will not put" which was a facecious remark attributed to Winston Churchill in 1948. I was born in 1949, I will say no more.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree with the correct(er) form. I was not trying to be pedantic, to be honest. But, yeah, paying that much attention might not be necessary. I just thought, pointing it out might be helpful since it is a legal notice.

Comment: "Whom" sounds stilted and old-fashioned. Which is OK, if that is the look you are going for. But I wouldn't be surprised if the current, or coming, generation has no idea what "whom" means. Which is absolutely fine.

Comment: @bengongon97 Quite. Please don't take me too seriously, I try not to. I was really trying to be funny but it often doesn't work well, particularly when I'm typing!

Comment: @BoldBen ah, I see. That's normal, unfortunately in this "typing world" with no-seeing-each-other during a conversation, emotions cannot be expressed correctly and some puns and jokes are gotten wrong. That's kinda a problem in this century but I am glad that you were joking :D I was surprised at first that how you understood that I was being pedantic in the first place since it was not intended at all. :)